# RxJava's switchOnNext method does not behave as JavaDoc described

Tags: rx-java

rx.Observable.switchOnNext(Observable>) does not behave as the marble diagram in JavaDoc described.

If I tried below

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Observable<Long> o1 = Observable.interval(200L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  Observable<Long> o2 = Observable.interval(500L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .map(value -> value * 10);

  Observable.switchOnNext(Observable.just(o1, o2)).subscribe(System.out::println);

  Thread.sleep(2000L);
}
```

The marble diagram shows that the result might be like below.

```
| time   | 0   | 200  | 400   | 500  | 1000   | 1500 |.....|
|--------|-----|------|-------|------|--------|------|-----|
| o1     |     | 0    | 1     |....  | ...    | ...  | ... |
| o2     |     |      |       | 0    |  10    | 20   | ... |
| result |     | 0    | 1     | 0    |  10    | 20   | ... |
```

But the result becomes 0, 10, 20...and so on like below

```
| time   | 0   | 200  | 400   | 500  | 1000   | 1500 |.....|
|--------|-----|------|-------|------|--------|------|-----|
| o1     |     | 0    | 1     |....  | ...    | ...  | ... |
| o2     |     |      |       | 0    |  10    | 20   | ... |
| result |     |      |       | 0    |  10    | 20   | ... |
```

Also, if I reverse o1 to o2 like `Observable.just(o1, o2)` to `Observable.just(o2, o1)`,
the result would be that only o1`s values were emitted.

Is this correct behavior?

if it is ether the [JavaDoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#switchOnNext%28rx.Observable%29) would be wrong or the program would be wrong, I will create the issue.

Or, do I misundersand the description?

I'm using RxJava 1.1.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess the Javadoc is correct in this case. You have to interpret the upper horizontal line as time as well. So what you give to `switchOnNext` is an `Observable` containing a first `Observable o1`, immediately followed by another `Observable o2`. So in the marble diagram the left diagonal line represents `o1`, the right diagonal line represents `o2`. Since the latter comes *immediately* after the former, the former is discarded, that's why you only see the latter in your output.

To get the expected behavior like it is in the marble diagram you can for example replace the `Observable.just(o1, o2)` with

```
Observable.timer(100L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).map(l -> o1)
          .concatWith(Observable.timer(600L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).map(l -> o2));
```

or anything along those lines.

The real use of this is to *unsubscribe from the first `Observable` when the second rolls around and subscribe to the second instead*.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Now, I know that I misunderstood `switchOnNext` method and I understand `switchOnNext`.  Since the observables were subscribed at the same time, the result did not come out what I expected.